# Selecting a web browser installed

Tags: c++, firefox, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I want to do the following:

Using ANSI c++ code

I want to check the browser installed (preferably the default one on a windows based machine) if a default browser is found

I will use wxlaunchdefaultwebbrowser - wxWidgets 2.8.12 ; else i simply want to locate internet explorer (the default versions of the same on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008) and use it with wxlaunchDefaultwebbrowser i am using wxWidgets 2.8.12.

I tested it on Win XP SP3 without mozilla being installed when i installed the mozilla firefox and set it as default browser manually he link got opened up.Where as earlier i had IE 6.0 probably and Chrome installed however it prompted cannot open with default browser (error 5 : access is denied).

So i am looking for most of the settings automatic (no manual settings)

Comment: On Windows, there's either A) a default handler set for URLs or B) no Web browser installed. Just call wxLaunchDefaultBrowser and it'll do what you want.

Comment: Without Linux/BSD/MacOS I wouldn't call this cross-platform

Comment: Same applies for Linux and OS X, can't say for BSD distros.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Windows API, please use "ShellExecute" API with URL which will open it in the default browser. btw, wxlaunchDefaultwebbrowser will launch the default browser right? You still want to know the default browser details?

Comment: Does he really want to start it? Or only know which one it is?

Comment: He mentioned he wanted to launch with wxlaunchDefaultwebbrowser ;) I believe the API will choose the default browser set!

Comment: Yes wxlaunchdefaultbrowser does chooses it own its own but i want the automation of the browser selection(IE preferably) in case nothing is set as default browser

Comment: I'm not sure if windows allows you to not have default web browser. And if it does you don't need full path as explorer.exe should be find automaticly as it should be present in one of %PATH% directory

Comment: @KamilKlimek can you elaborate

Comment: @KamilKlimek I think you have a typo. You mean `iexplore.exe`.

Comment: There is envoirment variable %PATH% were OS is looking for executables if they don't contain full path. If you open cmd and type iexplore.exe it should open even without a full path.